# Woocommerce SPA embedded on woocommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building a tool (SPA) which helps customers decide which product is best for them. The tool also allows them to make a purchase.

Built using vue.js, and originally intended to be embedded within a page on a Shopify store, I have been asked to replace Shopify with Woocommerce.

I've not used woocommerce in this way before (I typically use it as is, and make changes to templates via action hooks and templates).

The SPA will be embedded within a page on the woocommerce site. I see that woocommerce has an API, with various endpoints from which I can retrieve data, and post when a customer wishes to purchase.

Should I use this api, or, should I make woocommerce templates which return json? It seems sensible to use the API as its useful for this type of thing.

If using the API, will I need to authenticate against it using oauth etc? The SPA will exist within a page of the woocommerce site, within the same domain as the API.

Sorry, this is probably a poor question - I just need a nudge in the right direction. Does anyone have any pointers on the best way I should proceed? Thanks, Rob

Comment: From poking around, it seem the only way to do it is to make my own templates that output json, served up at specific slugs... I cannot use the API in the way that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [WooCommerce REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/), which uses [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).   Then you can use the builtin [Backbone Client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) with `wp_enqueue_script('wp-api');` and make use of the Backbone.Model and Collection to handle CRUD operations or other [JavaScript client libraries](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/client-libraries/#javascript).
You can [define your own REST Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).
I think this what you are looking for.
And there is of course the old friend [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) ;-)